# How to Integrate XMPP Server with play framework 2.2 for scala?

Tags: scala, websocket, xmpp, playframework-2.2

I am new to XMPP. I am unable to find a way to integrate XMPP Server with play framework 2.2. I want to use both web sockets and XMPP for my web application for chat. Any reference regarding this will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: wondering if you made any progress?